# I have a Bash file I want to edit it and change

Tags: bash

How can I change the 127.0.0.1 to another IP address using [echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) or [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) without [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) or [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)?

Here's the Bash command and the Bash file name is *listpics*:

```
python3 poc.py --cmd listPics --ip 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: either you have the file and can change it, or you don't.

Comment: Please do not tag a bunch of languages on a question arbitrarily. If you want to use a specific language to solve the problem, tag that language; if you haven't chosen a language, you *do not have a question for Stack Overflow yet*. This is not a discussion forum and we will not help you decide the "best tool for the job" - because we don't want arguments over that. Please also read [ask]. You need to explain how you tried to solve the problem already, what happens when you try your solution, and how that is different from what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific case, you could do this:

```python
with open('listpics', 'r+') as listpics:
    data = listpics.read().replace('127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.254')
    listpics.seek(0)
    listpics.write(data)
    listpics.truncate()
```

Comment: I want to change the ip from terminal I use termux for Android